Make a python app for reading iTunes work under both Windows and macOS
I'm writing an app to help set groupings in an iTunes library so that shuffle by grouping works for classical music (I'm surprised I couldn't find one). In windows I can use the code below and access the iTunes library as Python objects. What would I need to do to make the same code run under macOS and Windows?
import win32com.client
iTunesApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("iTunes.Application")
mainLibrary = iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist;
tracks = mainLibrary.Tracks;
for i in range(1,tracks.Count+1): 
...

